# Marking Emails Unread after Reading with imap_tools

Tags: python, imap-tools

I am trying to fetch unread emails using imap_tools then want to mark them as read. I have tried using `mark_seen` but I end up in an indefinite loop rereading the emails that have been marked as unread. Here's my code snippet:

```
msgs = client.fetch(AND(seen=False, date_gte=datetime.date(2021, 7, 30), subject='away'), mark_seen=False)
```

Comment: what about flag method?

Answer (score 0):

mark_seen  is True by default. You have disabled marking

Comment: I'm trying to mark fetched emails as unread. Is that possible?